# I am trying to write an encryption in Python. My Problem is that the key is shorter than the message. Therefore I should start again with the key

Tags: python, for-loop, encryption, modulo

i am writing an XOR encryption. If the message is longer than the key, it should start again at the beginning of the key.

```
message="wall"
key="code"
for m, k in zip(message,key):
    result=ord(m)^ord(k)
    print(result)
```

How can i manage this problem?
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: I think you should explain what kind of encryption you are trying to do. Provide a sample key, a sample message, what you expect as output, and why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally certain what you want, but if it's what I think it is there are many ways to do it. One of the shortest that preserves most of your code takes advantage of `itertools.cycle()` as in the following:

```py
from itertools import cycle

message="wallaby"
key="code"
for m, k in zip(message, cycle(key)):
    result=ord(m)^ord(k)
    print(result)
```